# Retrieve an object's class

Tags: c#, wpf

Right now, this is what I am doing to obtain the class of elements in my WPF canvas:

```
    // for instance
    private void R_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender.ToString() == "System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle")
        {
            // ok i am a rect
            System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle r = (System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle)sender;
            //etc...
        }
    }
```

Somehow I feel there is a more elegant way of doing this. Something in the lines of:

```
    if (class(sender) == System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle) ...
```

In other words, is there reflection in C# and if not, how to emulate it?

Comment: `if(sender is System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle) ...`

Comment: Also, be aware of `sender.GetType()`, and `sender as Rectangle`.

Comment: Since question is about WPF, you should know, that sender and event source for routed events can differ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [`is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) operator:

```
if (sender is System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle)
    // it's a rectangle
```

Or maybe better use the [`as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as) operator:

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle rect = sender as System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle;
if (rect != null)
{
   // do something with rect
}
```

but this will only work for classes, not for structs or other value types. If `sender` is not of that type, `rect` will be `null` (a *direct* cast like `(Rectangle)sender` would throw an `InvalidCastException` instead).

---

Note that both operators also work for base types. So if `sender` really is a `Rectangle`, `sender is Shape` will also return `true`.

Comment: Simple and elegant. Thanks!